# Click a button and the button would be unable to be clicked until reset

Tags: visual-studio, vba, button, boolean, basic

Is there a way I could be able to click a Button and then once the button has been clicked it would be Unable to be clicked until the Form reset itself.

Say... Enabling Auto-Save and can't be turned off until is Auto-Saves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.enabled(false);
```

and on reset

```
button.enabled(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you using visual basic 2010

button.enabled = false

and on reset

button.enabled = true

I hope this help.